# Find a generator of $Z_{27}^*$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know a generator $g \in Z_{27}^*$ means that the order of $g$ is $26$, but I'm having trouble finding an efficient method to find a generator given that the number of possibilities are very large (and the exponentiation to check that $g^x  = 1 \mod 27$ can get extremely tedious).

Are there any efficient ways to do this quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Hensel lifting. We know for sure that $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_3^*$, hence $2+0=2,2+3=5$ or $2+6=8$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$. Since the order of $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ is $\phi(9)=2\cdot 3=6$, we only need to check that $x^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{9}$ and $x^3\not\equiv 1\pmod{9}$. The second condition is clearly met since $x^3\equiv x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. So $x=2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$. Now at least one $y$ among $2,2+9,2+18$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_{27}^*$, whose order is $2\cdot 3^2=18$. We have to check $y^6\not\equiv 1\pmod{27}$ and $y^9\not\equiv 1\pmod{27}$, but $y^9=(y^3)^3\equiv y^3\equiv y\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, so the second one is free. This gives that $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_{27}^*$, for instance.